# Determining use of customize-set-variable versus setq

Tags: customization

How can I determine whether to use `customize-set-variable` rather than setq?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should "custom" variables defined without defcustom be set via custom-set-variables or setq?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32157/should-custom-variables-defined-without-defcustom-be-set-via-custom-set-variab)

Comment: It does not answer completely.  Is the use of `customize-set-variable` related to the use of a customization interface, of some minor-mode for instance?  How can I determine whether a variable should not me set with `setq`?